# Does Apollo Stack support global object identification like the node interface of Relay?

Tags: node.js, graphql, relay, apollostack

I am very new in both Apollo Stack and Relay. I am trying to choose between them to invest my time. After finish reading the book [Learning GraphQL and Relay](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/learning-graphql-and-relay), I turned to Apollo to learn what it has to offer but right now there are not much resources in the internet.

I have this question recently but unable to find the answer: Does Apollo support [global object identification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm) like Relay does with the node interface? if not, does it have any alternative solution to support global object identification?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**!

The way it currently works (version 0.5 of `apollo-client`) is with the `dataIdFromObject` function that the `ApolloClient` constructor accepts.

If all nodes got an `id` field and they are unique across all nodes (at Graphcool for example, we generate unique ids with [this library](https://github.com/graphcool/cuid-java)):

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});
```

You have to make sure to include the `id` field in every query you want to be normalized.

If your ids are only unique per type, you can combine them with `__typename` to create unique identifiers:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: (result) => {
    if (result.id && result.__typename) {
      return result.__typename + result.id;
    }

    // Make sure to return null if this object doesn't have an ID
    return null;
  },
});
```

The code is taken from the [official Apollo documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject).

Answer (score 3):

In `apollo-client` v2, You must pass `dataIdFromObject` to `InMemoryCache` instance instead.

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink(),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: object => object.id,
  }),
});
```